# How get unique key from multiple nested object

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to extract a specific unique key from a nested multiple object.

This is my stringify:

```
{
  "instance": {
    "$class": "org.accordproject.acceptanceofdelivery.AcceptanceOfDeliveryClause",
    "deliverable": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "businessDays": {
      "type": "Long"
    },
    "attachment": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "clauseId": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "parties": {
    "shipper": {
      "$class": "org.accordproject.organization.Organization",
      "identifier": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "optional": true
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "String",
        "optional": true
      },
      "duns": {
        "type": "String",
        "optional": true
      },
      "place": {
        "address": {},
        "geo": {
          "address": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "receiver": {
      "$class": "org.accordproject.organization.Organization",
      "identifier": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "optional": true
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "String",
        "optional": true
      },
      "duns": {
        "type": "String",
        "optional": true
      },
      "place": {
        "address": {},
        "geo": {
          "address": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "requestTypes": [
    {
      "$class": "org.accordproject.acceptanceofdelivery.InspectDeliverable",
      "deliverableReceivedAt": {
        "type": "DateTime"
      },
      "inspectionPassed": {
        "type": "Boolean"
      },
      "transactionId": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "DateTime"
      }
    }
  ],
  "responseTypes": [
    {
      "$class": "org.accordproject.acceptanceofdelivery.InspectionResponse",
      "status": {
        "$class": "org.accordproject.acceptanceofdelivery.InspectionStatus",
        "enum": [
          "PASSED_TESTING",
          "FAILED_TESTING",
          "OUTSIDE_INSPECTION_PERIOD"
        ]
      },
      "shipper": {
        "$class": "org.accordproject.organization.Organization",
        "identifier": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "String",
          "optional": true
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "String",
          "optional": true
        },
        "duns": {
          "type": "String",
          "optional": true
        },
        "place": {
          "$class": "org.accordproject.geo.Place",
          "address": {
            "$class": "org.accordproject.address.PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "postalCode": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "postOfficeBoxNumber": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "addressRegion": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "addressLocality": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "addressCountry": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            }
          },
          "branchCode": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "faxNumber": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "geo": {
            "$class": "org.accordproject.geo.GeoCoordinates",
            "address": {
              "$class": "org.accordproject.address.PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "postalCode": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "postOfficeBoxNumber": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "addressRegion": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "addressLocality": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "addressCountry": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              }
            },
            "addressCountry": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "elevation": {
              "type": "Double",
              "optional": true
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "Double",
              "optional": true
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "Double",
              "optional": true
            }
          },
          "globalLocationNumber": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "mapUrl": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "isicsV4": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "telephone": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          }
        }
      },
      "receiver": {
        "$class": "org.accordproject.organization.Organization",
        "identifier": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "String",
          "optional": true
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "String",
          "optional": true
        },
        "duns": {
          "type": "String",
          "optional": true
        },
        "place": {
          "$class": "org.accordproject.geo.Place",
          "address": {
            "$class": "org.accordproject.address.PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "postalCode": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "postOfficeBoxNumber": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "addressRegion": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "addressLocality": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "addressCountry": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            }
          },
          "branchCode": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "faxNumber": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "geo": {
            "$class": "org.accordproject.geo.GeoCoordinates",
            "address": {
              "$class": "org.accordproject.address.PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "postalCode": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "postOfficeBoxNumber": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "addressRegion": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "addressLocality": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              },
              "addressCountry": {
                "type": "String",
                "optional": true
              }
            },
            "addressCountry": {
              "type": "String",
              "optional": true
            },
            "elevation": {
              "type": "Double",
              "optional": true
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "Double",
              "optional": true
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "Double",
              "optional": true
            }
          },
          "globalLocationNumber": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "mapUrl": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "isicsV4": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          },
          "telephone": {
            "type": "String",
            "optional": true
          }
        }
      },
      "transactionId": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "DateTime"
      }
    }
  ],
  "stateTypes": [
    {
      "$class": "org.accordproject.cicero.contract.AccordContractState",
      "stateId": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    }
  ],
  "eventTypes": [
    {
      "$class": "org.accordproject.base.Event",
      "eventId": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "DateTime"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to iterate step by step inside this huge list of object but I'm always failing when I try to fetch "type" key from it.

This is my approach but I think a part of what I'm doing is wrong and that there is a better way to reach this goal

```
Object.keys(this.model).forEach(data => {
      Object.values(this.model[data]).forEach(test => {
        console.log(test);
      });
```

My best result is this:

[image: extract of my object iteration log]

I need to extract "type" key like a unique key, so I get no repetition about the key value (what I intend is one time "String", one time "DateTime" and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommand doing it in several steps.

1. Flatten your object in order to have a single level dept object
2. Loop over your keys to find the keys that finish by 'type'
3. Add to an array the distinct values you need

**Flatten object (will probably need some adaptation)**

```
flattenObject(ob) {
    var toReturn = {};

    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object' && ob[i] !== null) {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

                toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

**Loop over the keys and add to Array**

```
getUniqueTypeValues(flattenedObj) {
    const uniqueValues = [];

    Object.keys(flattenedObj).forEach(element => {
        if (typeof(element) !== 'string' || !element.endsWith('type')) {
            return;
        }

        const val = flattenedObj[element];
        if (uniqueValues.find(alreadyAddedValue => val === alreadyAddedValue) === undefined) {
            uniqueValues.push(val);
        }

return uniqueValues;

    });
}
```

**Full solution**

```
const yourObject = {}; // Get your input
const flattenedObj = flattenObject(yourObject);
return getUniqueTypeValues(flattenedObj);
```

You can see full solution here : https://jsfiddle.net/zrhyk3ap/

Hope it helps!